# Write a nested case expression

Tags: sql

I'm trying to write a condition to perform a test within a case expression. I've searched and can't find the correct syntax to use.

```
CASE WHEN a.amount - b.amount <> 0 
     then (CASE WHEN a.amount - C.amount <> 0 then 'EXCEPTION' end) 
     else 'PASS' end
```

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? They are not the same?

Comment: Just remove the brackets...

Comment: Please remove the inappropriate DBMS tag (which is SQL Server I assume). And if you got an error with your syntax, then you should tell us the error message, rather than have us guess.

Comment: @RTL . . . I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 0):

There is syntax issue I guess.

```
CASE 
     WHEN a.amount - b.amount <> 0 then 
     CASE 
         WHEN a.amount - C.amount <> 0 then 'EXCEPTION' 
              ELSE 'PASS'
         end 
     else 'PASS' 
end
```

Or

You may combine your nested case statement into one by using `AND` or `OR`.

```
CASE 
     WHEN (a.amount - b.amount) <> 0 AND (a.amount - C.amount) <> 0 
          then 'EXCEPTION'
     else 'PASS' end
```

Answer (score 0):

While this is valid SQL and should work in about every DBMS, MySQL is completely buggy here. I've played around with the expression and got it working by changing `C.amount` (uppercase c) to `c.amount` (lowercase c). Go figure :-(

Here is a demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0ff1d0c3010362db5263123dcb9f09ad